# Storing GCM Ids on my webserver using cordova not working

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to register GCM ids of various devices on my webserver so that I can send push notifications. I have used the following code to get the GCM id of a device.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                function onDeviceReady(){
                console.log("Device Ready")
                var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID":"989946143452"},
                "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

                push.on('registration', function(data) {
                console.log(data.registrationId);
                $("#gcm_id").html(data.registrationId);
                });

                push.on('notification', function(data) {
                console.log(data.message);
                alert(data.title+" Message: " +data.message);
                // data.title,
                // data.count,
                // data.sound,
                // data.image,
                // data.additionalData
                });

                push.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
                });
                }
</script>
```

Then I am using the following this form field to parse the gcm id from the javascript to the html form field,

```
<input type="hidden" name="gcm_id" id="gcm_id" required/>
```

The form field seems not to be getting the gcm_id value. Any workarounds on this?

Of couser I am using ajax to send the data to the php script that will store the gcm_id on my MySQL table.

Comment: are you sure you getting resgitration id?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice yes but I am unable to parse it into the html form field

Comment: are you using plugin for gcm or wrting independant code?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice I just want to populate the hidden form field with the registration id using the plugin. Any suggestions?

Comment: so are you sure you getting registration id using ur plugin ? if yes try to put  up into text field first

Comment: @MyMasterPeice still not working even if I use `<input type="text" name="gcm_id" id="gcm_id" />` but it populates to a `<p id="gcm_id"></p>`. Any ideas?

Comment: post how r u polulating

Comment: change this line $("#gcm_id").html(data.registrationId); to $("#gcm_id").val(data.registrationId);

Comment: @NareshKumar not working either

Comment: Managed to solve it. The issue was with my ajax submission script.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer the question as I just realize that the error was on my ajax submission script. Here is the entire script that is working perfectly. Note the changes I made on `$("#gcm_id").html(data.registrationId);` to `$("#gcm_id").text(data.registrationId);`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        function onDeviceReady(){
        console.log("Device Ready")
        var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

        push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
        //$("#gcm_id").html(data.registrationId);
        $("#gcm_id").text(data.registrationId);
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/gcmreg.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {registrationId: data.registrationId},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                    });
        });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);
        alert(data.title+" Message: " +data.message);
        // data.title,
        // data.count,
        // data.sound,
        // data.image,
        // data.additionalData
        });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        });
        }
        </script>
```